# How to get x amount of letters from some text in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my component, I want to do this: if the text has 50 letters show them and if it has more than 50 show the text and ...

```js
const Post: React.FC = ({
  text
}) => {
  return ( <p> {text} </p> );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that using slice(starting value, ending value)

```js
<p> {text ? .length >= 50 ? text ? .slice(0, 50) + "..." : text} </p>
```